# Setting image height, but limit image size by width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my img to have height:18em, but when the website is loaded in mobile view, I want the img to be as high as possible, but without the img exceeding width:100%.

What is the CSS code for the img?

My current code is:

```css
.img{
  height: 18em;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

But when loaded in mobile view, height and width of the image are not proportional to each other. Height stays at 18em, and width contracts to 100%.
I want the image to **scale** to have 100% width.

I know this is a simple question, but I just can't make it work. I'm using images with ratios 16:9 and 1:1 so I always run into a problem...
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `height:auto` in mobile view

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .img {
       height: auto;
       max-width: 100%;
     }
}
```

Comment: This does it perfectly! Thank you for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

Using Media Screen to check mobile size first, and you can set your mobile version's CSS into media screen area

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .img{
       height: 9em;
       max-width: 100%;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does replacing `height` with `max-height` do the trick?

If not, you should probably use some media queries to enhance the ux on mobile views and desktop views.